# How to count number of the same elements in array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having very simple issue. 
I have array

```
 $a = array('dog', 'dog', 'dog', 'mouse', 'mouse','mouse', 'cat','cat');
```

How to count how many elements called 'dog' I have ?
I tried `count()` function , i know it's not good because count doesn't look into array only counts number of elements.

So for example answer for my issue would be :

```
 dog = 3 
 mouse = 3
 cat = 2
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`array_count_values()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php):

```
print_r(array_count_values($a));

Array
(
    [dog] => 3
    [mouse] => 3
    [cat] => 2
)

$count = array_count_values($a);
echo $count['dog']; // prints 3
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to use `array-count-values`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

```
print_r(array_count_values($a));

Array
(
    [dog] => 3
    [mouse] => 3
    [cat] => 2
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the [array_count_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) function.

```
$a = array('dog', 'dog', 'dog', 'mouse', 'mouse','mouse', 'cat','cat');

$counted = array_count_values($a);

$numberOfDogs = $counted['dog'];
```

Answer (score 2):

[`array_count_values();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

Given your input:

```
$a = array('dog', 'dog', 'dog', 'mouse', 'mouse','mouse', 'cat','cat');
$var = array_count_values($a);
var_dump($var);
```